# Randomly Generate Even Split of 1s and 0s in Array

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I have a simple array, 20 members long, that I read a single value from, one at a time.

The array currently looks like this for testing purposes:

```
int PhaseTesting1Array[20] = { 1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0};
```

What I need to do is randomize each of the members so that each member is randomly a 1 or 0, and there is an equal amount of each (10 ones and 10 zeros) but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do get an equal number of ones and zeros using `rand` which seems to be what I should use.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is what's called a [random *shuffle*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: ***using rand which seems to be what I should use*** Unless this is an academic requirement `rand()` should no longer be used in c++ since 2011. It has been replaced with the random library.

Comment: @drescherjm -- `rand()` works just fine for quick and dirty coding. And it's conceptually simpler than the `<random>` stuff, so easier for beginners to grapple with. Sometimes quickly getting code that works is better than struggling with more complex approaches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `std::shuffle` with a predefined vector with 10 ones and 10 zeros. The following code is slightly adapted from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
 
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
 
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
 
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

You could also use `std::random_shuffe(I first, I last)` without the random number distribution argument which uses `rand` internally, but this is deprecated and removed with C++17.